# Python/PyCharm mark "unused" import as used

Tags: python

I need to import a **resource_rc.py** file in my module. It is immediately marked by PyCharm as "unused". Is there a way to mark "unused" imports and also variables, etc. as used in Python?

I came up with the idea to just:

```
import resource_rc
del resource_rc

# do something with the imported stuff
```

It works, but is that correct? Can that cause a problem?

Comment: Is there a reason that having static analysis derived markup in your IDE be 100% correct is so important?  I definitely wouldn't actually modify the code to get static analysis to work as you wish.  If it works at runtime, don't modify the code to make the IDE happy.  Also, are you using an `import *`?  If you are, that would be one of the few times I would say you should be modifying your code, but only because it is bad practice to do that.

Comment: What does `resource_rc` *do* that you need to import it, yet never use the name once?

Comment: @Silas Ray I am not that versed in Python. So any warnings scare me. So if you say it's not a problem - then I guess it is OK. "Also, are you using an import *?" - No, I am not that bad I hope!

Comment: Python is a highly dynamic language.  Static code analyzers can't catch everything, as lots of state doesn't exist outside of runtime.  If you are getting an "unused" warning on an import or variable, but you actually are using it, then there is nothing to worry about.  If you aren't actually using it, then you should just eliminate the statement with the warning.

Comment: @chepner I resource file with icons used by PyQt - QMainWindow.

Comment: Yes, but a line like `import resource_rc` doesn't import anything *except* the name `resource_rc` into the global namespace. If you aren't using the name, then how are you using anything that the module provides? Unless you provide more detail on how you are using `resource_rc`, the obvious answer seems to be "don't import it".

Comment: Are you *sure* it works when you do the `del` immediately after the `import`? If it does, then you're not really "doing something with the imported stuff" (as you say in the code comment) but rather just *executing* `resource_rc` for its side-effects.

Comment: Sometimes imports are required for their implicit side-effects. For example, in SQLAlchemy, you might need to import an external model in order to register its relationship to an existing model, but you don't actually want to use the imported class name for any other reason.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is:

```
import something
assert something, "Something is imported for its side effects."
```

You *can* do this:

```
_ = something
```

But then you have an unused variable so you're relying on your static analyser treating `_` as a special variable name.

`assert` is also nice because it makes it really obvious why you're doing something that you really shouldn't do. (If you wrote `resource_rc` you should really really really change it so it doesn't have `import` side effects.)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
import json
_ = json.dump
```

Comment: There's no good reason to do this.  You are just abusing the code conventions of Python to trick the IDE's static analysis.  If you've managed to trick the static analyzer, unless you have a good reason, it's probably a sign that there's a real problem with your code, and you shouldn't be patching over it with a hack in the application code just to make the IDE happy.

Comment: @Silas Ray. Not sure why you downvoted my answer.  It's a solution to the problem, even if you believe the problem is a symptom of poor design.

Comment: What I sometimes do is something like {{assert json}}. It looks better.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but it showed up when I was googling.
Here's the answer to save someone a few minutes of their life.

You can suppress any inspections﻿ for specific line in PyCharm with `# noqa` comment.
This works for unused imports including Optimize Imports command.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Comment: What a nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

This is not abusing PyCharm's analysis. For example, if you have something like :

```
globals()[className]
```

which refers to the class named className and className is a string, then PyCharm can't deduce which class you're using. And that's just some metacode, nothing fancy...