# Mark unused imported items in Python

Tags: python

In Python if you need to import a module for its side effects then you can't use something like [`autoflake`](https://pypi.org/project/autoflake/) to automatically remove unused `import`s. There's a fairly clean way to work around that that I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69134155/265521) (I didn't come up with it but I don't remember where I saw it):

```py
import something
assert something, "Something is imported for its side effects."
```

But what if you are importing something so that it is re-exported. In other words:

```py
# api.py
from internal_details import version
```

```py
# main.py
import api
print(api.version)
```

Unfortunately Python is not well enough designed to have an `export` statement, so there's no way for `autoflake` to know that you imported `version` just to expose it to other modules.

What's the cleanest way to mark `version` as unused? Note that you can't do the same thing as the with the module:

```
assert version, "Version is part of the exported API."
```

That won't work (exercise for the reader!).

The best I can come up with is:

```
assert True or version, "Version is part of the export API."
```

But it's a bit ugly. Is there a better solution?

To be clear, I don't want to use lint-disabling comments like `# noqa` unless there is one that is de facto supported by everyone. Autoflake was just an example; Pylint also does this analysis. There's probably more.

Comment: A hack-y, but probably usable solution might be to make an unused function in the api.py that just uses the version import for something random (e.g. just print(api.version)). There are probably better solutions but as a workaround I think this is worth mentioning

Comment: Append `# noqa` to the line?

Comment: The whole approach might be an anti-pattern. If you import version in api for the only reason to be able to import it later from api, this looks like bad module design to me. But I might be wrong. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I've never heard of `autoflake` before but I think the closest thing Python has to an `export` statement is `__all__`. Try adding `__add__ = ('version',)` to the top of the file.

Comment: From the `autoflake` PyPI page you linked to: *By default, autoflake only removes unused imports for modules that are part of the standard library. (Other modules may have side effects that make them unsafe to remove automatically.) Removal of unused variables is also disabled by default.* So if you do `from internal_details import version`, you're fine, because the tool you're using is smart enough to foresee this situation. So what's your problem?

Comment: @MattDMo Because I want to use the non-default option. Also it isn't *just* autoflake. Pylint will also warn about unused imports. @jarmod That's another reason I don't want `# noqa` - I'd have to add lint disabling comments for every tool that does this analysis.

Comment: Why does asserting "not work"?

Comment: What if `version` is 0? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making your intention clearer by assigning `internal_details.version` to a local variable in `api`?

```py
# api.py
import internal_details
version = internal_details.version
```

Then

```py
# main.py
import api
print(api.version)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [autoflake](https://github.com/myint/autoflake) tool can ignore certain imports that you are not using directly.

Append `# noqa` to the relevant import line. For example:

```
from .endpoints import role, token, user, utils  # noqa
```

Comment: Autoflake was just an example. I want a method that does this for all tools that support this kind of analysis. E.g. we also use Pylint. I'll clarify the question.